# Best way to run Julia code in an IPython notebook (or Python code in an IJulia notebook)

Tags: python, ipython, julia

My goal is to run only a few lines of Julia in an IPython notebook where the majority of the code will be Python for some experiments ...

I found a nice example notebook here:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/blob/master/python/doc/JuliaMagic.ipynb

And now I am wondering how I would install the IPython extension for Julia (I am primarily using IPython 2.1) so that I can load it via

```
%load_ext julia.magic
```

---

I am also very new to julia and I am wondering if there is a performance benefit of "mixing numpy and julia" as shown in this notebook (over regular Python numpy or regular Julia code)

When I understand the concept correctly, I would use IJulia notebooks (which I set up successfully) if I am only interested in running Julia code?

I installed IJulia, and i can also run IJulia notebooks, but I actually only wanted to have a small portion of Julia code in my notebook, the rest should be Python / Cython.
Unfortunately, I read that magic functions are not yet fully supported: "One difference from IPython is that the IJulia kernel currently does not support "magics", which are special commands prefixed with % or %% to execute code in a different language"

Is there a way to run Python code in IJulia notebooks?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Run Julia inside an IPython notebook

### Hack

In order to run Julia snippets (or *other* language) inside an IPython notebook, I just append the string `'julia'` to the **`default`** list in the `_script_magics_default` method from the `ScriptMagics` class in:

- `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py` or
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py`.

#### Example:

```
# like this:
defaults = [
    'sh',
    'bash',
    'perl',
    'ruby',
    'python',
    'python2',
    'python3',
    'pypy',
    'julia', # add your own magic
]
```

- [Example notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/Ismael-VC/ae10c11d535f6741d8be/raw/4fa2f4c40fa7acc8c6e440ef34afd148b7c3f7d2/julia_magic.ipynb) (using Python3)

[image: IPython *Julia magic*]

### Julia Magic (Bi-directional)

To use `%load_ext julia.magic`, you would need to run the `setup.py` here:

***Update (09/04/2014)***: the `setup.py` file has been moved to pyjulia.jl:

- https://github.com/JuliaLang/pyjulia

<strike>Which you get when `Pkg.add("IJulia")` clones the repo in your filesystem:</strike>

```
cd ~/.julia/v0.3/IJulia/python/
sudo python2 setup.py install
```

Currently this only works for me in *Python2*. Python3 complains about:

```
ImportError: No module named 'core'
```

when I try to load the extention, but installs without complains.

After installing it you can also do this from inside Python2:

```
from julia import Julia
j = Julia()
arr = j.run('[1:10]')
type(arr) # numpy.ndarray
```

- http://blog.leahhanson.us/julia-calling-python-calling-julia.html

### Runing a script from your system *shell*

Use the *shell* mode syntax in a notebook cell:

```
!julia my_script.jl
```

---

## Run Python inside IJulia notebook

### Using PyCall

It's not really *running* python code in the context you want, but you can also use Python libraries from within Julia:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport math
println(math.pi)
```

- https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl

### Runing a script from your system *shell*

Use the *shell* mode syntax in a notebook cell:

```
;python my_script.py
```

- http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/interacting-with-julia/?highlight=shell#shell-mode

Comment: The link to the `setup.py` file for julia.magic is broken. After some searching I found that it was removed from IJulia: https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/commit/fe3a497f3e05b511013db6d0122157ea855a5800. It now lives in pyjulia:https://github.com/JuliaLang/pyjulia

Comment: @AlexWilliams thanks for the update! I was also starting to wonder what had happened.

Comment: Link to Example notebook (using Python3) broken

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use [Beaker](http://beakernotebook.com). They have a [tutorial notebook](http://sharing.beakernotebook.com/gist/anonymous/11152408) available that mixes R and Python; using Julia is just as easy.

Comment: There has also been a recent effort, that will abstract the python agnostic parts of IPython into a separate project called Jupyter! http://jupyter.org/

Answer (score 8):

If you want to run a whole notebook of **only** julia (or where you call other languages only from julia), then there is a cleaner solution.  First, launch julia and do

```
Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

to get the IJulia package.  Then you can

```
ipython notebook --profile julia
```

and your notebook will have julia as the native (default) language.

h/t to David Sanders and his [excellent julia tutorials](https://github.com/dpsanders/scipy_2014_julia) that are written in IPython notebooks; [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWkgEddb4-A).

Answer (score 2):

To complete [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24106944/), Without any hack, and without modifying any system file, a simple solution is with [the `%%script` magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=magic#cellmagic-script):

```
In [1]: %%script julia
   ...: println("Hi from a Julia sub-process")
   ...: a = [1:10]
```

Be cautious that the cell was run in a sub-process, so whatever was done in it is **not accessible** by the rest of the IPython session:

```
In [2]: print("Hi from the main IPython process")
   ...: print(a)  # <-- not available from the Julia code, will fail !
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c5a4f3535135> in <module>()
----> 1 print(a)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks! I just started some discussion to make that hack functionaity offcial and supported, see: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10834

Answer (score 0):

A clean and nice method is described in this notebook: https://github.com/binder-examples/julia-python/blob/master/python-and-julia.ipynb.

It strongly uses IPython magic (`%julia <julia code>` inlined in Python, and `%%julia` cells), but the result is quite impressive: the two Python and Julia processes can use the same variables and memory.